# Show "empty" mysql fields in form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that is shown as long as there is no data available in the respective mysql table, see below:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($records)==0)) {...}
```

As soon as data is available in the respective table I'm showing a separate table which basically contains the same information as the "empty" table but includes the fetched values from the mysql table:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {...}
```

**Question 1:** How can I merge these two tables into one so that if NO data is available the field value is empty and if data is added to the mysql data base the value will be shown in the respective field?

**Question 2:** Are there any suggestions on how to simplify the code as there will be many more rows (teams) added to the form table?

**Code:**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE user = '"
    .$_SESSION['username']."'";
$records = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($records)==0) {
    ?>
    <form action="xxxxx.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Home</th>
                <th width="40%"></th>
                <th width="30%">Away</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Team 1</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                           name="team1game1">
                    :
                    <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                           name="team2game1">
                </td>
                <td><label>Team 2</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Team 3</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                           name="team3game1">
                    :
                    <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                           name="team4game1">
                </td>
                <td><label>Team 4</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else {
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
        ?>
        <form action="xxxxx.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%">Home</th>
                    <th width="40%"></th>
                    <th width="30%">Away</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Team 1</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                               name="team1game1"
                               value="<?php echo $result['team1game1'] ?>">
                        :
                        <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                               name="team2game1"
                               value="<?php echo $result['team2game1'] ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><label>Team 2</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Team 3</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                               name="team3game1"
                               value="<?php echo $result['team3game1'] ?>">
                        :
                        <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" 
                               name="team4game1"
                               value="<?php echo $result['team4game1'] ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><label>Team 4</label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I notice that even when there is no data, you're showing 2 rows of inputs for teams 1-4. You also mentioned that you will have a lot of rows. Question 1: So if you have 100 teams but no data, will you show 50 rows of empty inputs?  Question 2: When you have data, creating a new table with each record. So 50 records would mean 50 tables. Is this intentional?

Comment: It looks like you have 1 column for each team in your table in the database. Can it be changed to that you store data of team in a row instead?

Comment: @Patrick I guess I'll have to be a little more precise. I'm currently developping a betting game. The table posted above belongs to the page where users can enter their guesses for each game/match. Now I did not want to have two different pages - one if user has not yet entered any guesses/bets (insert only) and one to show their guesses/bets once they have entered them (update). Is it a little more clear now?

Comment: Sorry Mario I still don't know the answer to either of my 2 questions. (1) You chose to show empty inputs when you have no data; do you plan to do this even with lots of games? (so 50 rows of empty inputs if there are 50 game but no data). (2) I notice that when there is data, you build a new table in each loop. For each result in `$records`, you have a new form containing its own table. Is this intended?  Anyway I think the answer you received has some good ideas, especially about building the template string first, then outputting it in one step.

Comment: @Patrick (1) Yes, I plan to do this with up to around 50 games. (2) No, this is not itended and can be improved if there is a way.

Comment: @Patrick The best solution would be to have 1 table that allows to insert NEW values if sql table is empty (i.e. fields are empty on pageload) OR UPDATE existing values if there are values in the table. If it helps I can post the "xxxxx.php" (action that is perfomed upon submit) - this function is valid for both "tables" and does either insert new values or update existing ones (INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you're asking for. Maybe you can provide an example of what it should be/look like for a better understanding.

However, here's at least a slightly optimised version of your code:

```
<?php
// Always escape values received from the user before using them
// in SQL queries
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

$template = '
<form action="xxxxx.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Home</th>
            <th width="40%"></th>
            <th width="30%">Away</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Team 1</label></td>
            <td><input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" name="team1game1" value="%team1game1%"> : <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" name="team2game1" value="%team2game1%"></td>
            <td><label>Team 2</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Team 3</label></td>
            <td><input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" name="team3game1" value="%team3game1%"> : <input type="tel" size="1" maxlength="2" name="team4game1" value="%team4game1%"></td>
            <td><label>Team 4</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE user = '".$user."'";
$records = mysql_query($sql);

$html = '';
if (mysql_num_rows($records)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
        $html  .= $template;
        $html   = str_replace('%team1game1%', $row['team1game1'], $html);
        $html   = str_replace('%team2game1%', $row['team2game1'], $html);
        $html   = str_replace('%team3game1%', $row['team3game1'], $html);
        $html   = str_replace('%team4game1%', $row['team4game1'], $html);
    }
} else {
    $html  .= $template;
    $html   = str_replace('%team1game1%', '', $html);
    $html   = str_replace('%team2game1%', '', $html);
    $html   = str_replace('%team3game1%', '', $html);
    $html   = str_replace('%team4game1%', '', $html);
}

// Print built HTML
echo $html;
?>
```

What it does:

- Store a form template in $template with variables (%var%) as placeholders
- Replace all variables (%var%) with str_replace() on each run

Some tips:

- Use PDO or at least MySQLi. mysql_*() functions are deprecated since ages and removed in current PHP versions. Relying on them will result in compatibility and security problems.
- When not working with an ORM, always escape values you receive from the user before putting them into SQL queries. Otherwise, you'll be vulnerable to SQL injections.